# fancy css float + clearing

Tags: css

Okay, I have four divs of unknown height, but fixed width. Although height is unknown, it can be assumed that div1 > div3 > div2. They are (currently) all in a row, floated. For example:

```
1111 2222 3333 4444
1111 2222 3333 4444
1111 2222 3333
1111      3333
1111
```

When I resize the viewport, I'd like the rightmost element to reposition itself, but into the "highest" possible position, and *not* clearing what is immediately left of it. Eg:

```
1111 2222 3333
1111 2222 3333
1111 2222 3333
1111 4444 3333
1111 4444
```

(this is not what happens under ordinary circumstances. 4 is positioned further down, such that it clears the bottom of 3)

And, on the next resize, the most "compact" arrangement, like so:

```
1111 2222
1111 2222
1111 2222
1111 3333
1111 3333
4444 3333
4444
```

(and again, 4 would be normally positioned lower down, such that it clears 3).

And lastly:

```
1111
1111
1111
1111
1111
2222
2222
2222
3333
3333
3333
4444
4444
```

I've tried some very creative arrangements, wrapping certain pairs of divs in a container div and applying different styles to that, positioning some elements absolutely, setting min / max widths on container divs, invisible shims, etc, etc. I've had success for some of these scenarios, but no solution is successful in all 4 possibilities. Any ideas? Also, I will not use javascript-- I'm looking for a pure-css solution, if it exists. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a live example we could play with? For example, at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Please post what you've tried already (i.e., the success for some of the scenarios)

Comment: autofit floats is among the most desired features of css but still never achieved in a generic manner. the order of the DIV will always override any css you can imagne. and that is why there cannot be a pure css solution. css can only style and move it around the space available but css can never move the DIV from first child to being the third child of the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this as the markup:

```
<div class="column" id="col-1"><h2>One</h2></div>
<div class="column" id="col-2"><h2>Two</h2></div>
<div class="column" id="col-3"><h2>Three</h2></div>
<div class="column" id="col-4"><h2>Four</h2></div>
```

With media queries, you can adjust the styles based on the size of the viewport:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.column {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.column h2 { text-align: center; }

#col-1 { padding: 400px 0; background: #ccf; }
#col-2 { padding: 200px 0; background: #fcc; }
#col-3 { padding: 300px 0; background: #cfc; }
#col-4 { padding: 100px 0; background: #ccc; }

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  body { width: 600px; }
  #col-3 { float: right; }
  #col-4 { display: block; float: none; }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  body { width: 400px; }
  #col-1, #col-4 { float: left; clear: left; }
  #col-2, #col-3 { float: right; clear: right; }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  body { width: 200px; }
  .column { display: block; float: none; }
}
```

[Try it in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHDwr/).

The drawback is that these media queries aren't supported in IE8 and less. However, you can fake this with a minimal amount of javascript that sets a class on your document body when the window is resized: then you can specify your CSS selections based on that, e.g. 
`body.width-200 .column { /* ... */ }`.